# Get saved accentColor and use it when the app restarts

Tags: android, ios, flutter, themes, sharedpreferences

i want to change app accentColor in runtime and save it into SharedPreferences, and i want when the app load the saved accentColor and apply it when the app restarts or relaunched.
here's my try:

```
class ThemeChange extends ChangeNotifier {
Color accentColor = myColor;
void getColor() async{

SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
if(prefs.getInt("app_color") == null){
 accentColor = myColor;
 notifyListeners();
}
else if(prefs.getInt("app_color") !=null){
  accentColor = Color(prefs.getInt("app_color"));
  notifyListeners();
}


}


void changeColor(Color color) {
this.accentColor = color;
notifyListeners();
}
}
```

and the way i used to save the color:

```
 Color color = myColor;
prefs.setInt("app_color", color.value);
setState(() {
  Provider.of<ThemeChange>(context, listen: false)
      .changeColor(myColor);
});
}
```

my code in main.dart:

```
 return ChangeNotifierProvider<ThemeChange>(
      create: (context) => ThemeChange(),
      child: Consumer<ThemeChange>(
        builder: (context, themechange, child) {
          return GetMaterialApp(
            debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
            title: "Flutter Localization Demo",
            theme: ThemeData(accentColor: themechange.accentColor),
```

my effort is not doing that much, so any optimal way to achieve that?

Comment: I think you are not using provider correctly.

Comment: @Doc can you provide me with optimal usage?